# Disadvantages of extremely large MAX_FILESIZE

Tags: hadoop, hbase

One of our HBase tables had grown to over 1000 regions. We reduced this by changing the MAX_FILESIZE property of the table from he default 256MB to 10GB. Now we are down to ~70 regions.

I was wondering what the side effect of this change would be? In other words, what are the disadvantages of increasing the MAX_FILESIZE of a table? What would happen if we increased the MAX_FILESIZE to 100GB or even 1TB?

My initial suspicion is that compactions would slow down considerably, but I want to be sure. What do you guys think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One significant issue is the amount of parallelism that you can get out of your cluster, if you are using M/R to process your data.  As Praveen points out, the [HBase book](http://hbase.apache.org/book/important_configurations.html) puts it this way: "Another issue is the effect of the number of regions on mapreduce jobs. Keeping 5 regions per RS would be too low for a job, whereas 1000 will generate too many maps. "

Their rule's of thumb for the number of regions is based on assumptions about how large your cluster is -- if you actually have 1000 map slots available, then 1000 regions would be fine.  My rule of thumb would be more along the lines of 2-3 times more regions than the number of map slots. Subject to all of the other points they bring up.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Section 2.5.2.6 [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book/important_configurations.html) for the optimal region size and number of regions per region server recommendations.